# How do i resolve type annotations needed cannot infer type for type parameter `T` ? What type annotation is needed to compile this code?

Tags: rust, blockchain

The blockchain struct definition, It defines a type and i use the type

```
pub struct Blockchain<T = SledDb> {
    pub storage: T,
    pub chain: Vec<Block>,
    pub tip: Arc<RwLock<String>>,
    pub height: AtomicUsize,
    pub mempool: Mempool,
    pub wallet: Wallet,
    pub accounts: Account,
    pub stakes: Stake,
    pub validators: Validator,
}
```

This code is checking if stake is valid.The code for mining a block, the error is immited by is_staking_valid function. I don't know what type its asking for since i already specified one.

```
impl<T: Storage> Blockchain<T> {
    pub fn is_staking_valid(
            balance: u64,
            difficulty: u32,
            timestamp: i64,
            prev_hash: &String,
            address: &String,
        ) -> bool {
            let base = BigUint::new(vec![2]);
            let balance_diff_mul = base.pow(256) * balance as u32;
            let balance_diff = balance_diff_mul / difficulty as u64;
    
            let data_str = format!("{}{}{}", prev_hash, address, timestamp.to_string());
            let sha256_hash = digest(data_str);
            let staking_hash = BigUint::parse_bytes(&sha256_hash.as_bytes(), 16).expect("msg");
    
            staking_hash <= balance_diff
        }
    pub fn mine_block(&mut self, data: &str) -> Option<Block> {

        if self.mempool.transactions.len() < 2 {
            info!("Skipping mining because no transaction in mempool");
            return None;
        }

        let balance = self
            .stakes
            .get_balance(&self.wallet.get_public_key())
            .clone();

        let difficulty = self.get_difficulty();
        info!("New block mining initialized with difficulty {}", difficulty);

        let timestamp = Utc::now().timestamp();
        let prev_hash = self.chain.last().unwrap().hash.clone();
        let address = self.wallet.get_public_key();


        if Blockchain::is_staking_valid(balance, difficulty, timestamp, &prev_hash, &address){

        let block = self.create_block(&data, timestamp);
        self.storage.update_blocks(&prev_hash, &block, self.height.load(Ordering::Relaxed));
        Some(block)
        } else {
           None
        }
    }
}
```

Please find the compiler error below

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
   --> src/blocks/chain.rs:173:12
    |
173 |         if Blockchain::is_staking_valid(balance, difficulty, timestamp, &prev_hash, &address){
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `T`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0282`.
```

Comment: you should at least post the errors you get. Otherwise we are blindfolded here.

Comment: Hi @Netwave, i have updated it with the compiler error

Comment: What's the definition of `Blockchain`? Looks like the type parameter `T` is there, since there's nothing generic in the code you've shown.

Comment: @Cerberus i have updated the code with the full definitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimized example:

```
pub struct Blockchain<T> {
    pub storage: T,
}

impl<T> Blockchain<T> {
    pub fn is_staking_valid() {
        todo!()
    }
    pub fn mine_block(&mut self) {
        Blockchain::is_staking_valid();
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f751d3e7130f0ca8f608230c3b8821c5)

The reason for this error is that `Blockchain::<T1>::is_staking_valid` and `Blockchain::<T2>::is_staking_valid` are, as well as compiler is concerned, two separate, entirely unrelated functions. Yes, they have the same code, and yes, they will be deduplicated by the optimizer, but this doesn't have to be the case - e.g., if this function used some associated item available on `T`:

```
trait Stakable {
    const IS_VALID: bool;
}
impl Stakable for () {
    const IS_VALID: bool = false;
}
impl Stakable for i32 {
    const IS_VALID: bool = true;
}

struct Blockchain<T> {
    pub _storage: T,
}

impl<T: Stakable> Blockchain<T> {
    fn validate() {
        if !T::IS_VALID {
            panic!("Type is not valid");
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // This panics - we catch this panic and show that it has indeed happened
    std::panic::catch_unwind(|| Blockchain::<()>::validate()).unwrap_err();
    // This executes successfully
    Blockchain::<i32>::validate();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c81e94e7f4f2da352d6ee274f091e9ad)

Because of the possible ambiguity, compiler refuses to choose by itself and forces you to make the selection explicitly.

---

So, you have several possible ways to go:

- Make `is_staking_valid` a free function, instead of associated function of `Blockchain`. In this case, it won't be able to depend on `Blockchain`'s type parameter, therefore the call will be unambiguous.
- Call `Self::is_staking_valid` instead of `Blockchain::is_staking_valid`. In this case, `Self` will be replaced with `Blockchain::<T>`, with `T` taken from the currently executed method; this will, again, resolve ambiguity.
- Make `is_staking_valid` a method on `Blockchain`, i.e. make it receive `&self`, and call it via `self.is_staking_valid()`.
- Not recommended, but still possible, - make `is_staking_valid` an associated function on `Blockchain<T>` for *some specific* `T`, e.g.:

```
pub struct Blockchain<T> {
    pub storage: T,
}

impl Blockchain<()> {
    // Note - no free type parameters here!
    pub fn is_staking_valid() {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl<T> Blockchain<T> {
    pub fn mine_block(&mut self) {
        // Here, `Blockchain` is `Blockchain::<()>` - the method is set
        Blockchain::is_staking_valid();
    }
}
```